# How to serialize my SOAP request class with namespaces using XmlMapper?

Tags: java, xml, soap, xmlmapper

For a SOAP API I need to POST a request XML in the following format:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws1="http://ws1.myapi.ch/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ws1:Suchen>
      <ws1:Benutzername>test</ws1:Benutzername>
      <ws1:Passwort>test</ws1:Passwort>
      <ws1:Sprache>De</ws1:Sprache>
      <ws1:Datenname>Arten</ws1:Datenname>
      <ws1:Einstellungen></ws1:Einstellungen>
    </ws1:Suchen>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In my Java code I have the following POJO for this:

```xml
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "benutzername",
    "passwort",
    "sprache",
    "datenname",
    "suchwerte",
    "einstellungen"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Suchen")
public class Suchen {

    @XmlElement(name = "Benutzername")
    protected String benutzername;
    @XmlElement(name = "Passwort")
    protected String passwort;
    @XmlElement(name = "Sprache")
    protected String sprache;
    @XmlElement(name = "Datenname")
    protected String datenname;
    @XmlElement(name = "Suchwerte")
    protected String suchwerte;
    @XmlElement(name = "Einstellungen")
    protected String einstellungen;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the benutzername property.
     *
     * @return possible object is {@link String }
     */
    public String getBenutzername() {
        return benutzername;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the benutzername property.
     *
     * @param value allowed object is {@link String }
     */
    public void setBenutzername(String value) {
        this.benutzername = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the passwort property.
     *
     * @return possible object is {@link String }
     */
    public String getPasswort() {
        return passwort;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the passwort property.
     *
     * @param value allowed object is {@link String }
     */
    public void setPasswort(String value) {
        this.passwort = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the sprache property.
     *
     * @return possible object is {@link String }
     */
    public String getSprache() {
        return sprache;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the sprache property.
     *
     * @param value allowed object is {@link String }
     */
    public void setSprache(String value) {
        this.sprache = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the datenname property.
     *
     * @return possible object is {@link String }
     */
    public String getDatenname() {
        return datenname;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the datenname property.
     *
     * @param value allowed object is {@link String }
     */
    public void setDatenname(String value) {
        this.datenname = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the suchwerte property.
     *
     * @return possible object is {@link String }
     */
    public String getSuchwerte() {
        return suchwerte;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the suchwerte property.
     *
     * @param value allowed object is {@link String }
     */
    public void setSuchwerte(String value) {
        this.suchwerte = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the einstellungen property.
     *
     * @return possible object is {@link String }
     */
    public String getEinstellungen() {
        return einstellungen;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the einstellungen property.
     *
     * @param value allowed object is {@link String }
     */
    public void setEinstellungen(String value) {
        this.einstellungen = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Suchen suchen = (Suchen) o;
        return Objects.equals(benutzername, suchen.benutzername) && Objects.equals(passwort, suchen.passwort) && Objects.equals(sprache, suchen.sprache)
                && Objects.equals(datenname, suchen.datenname) && Objects.equals(suchwerte, suchen.suchwerte) && Objects.equals(einstellungen,
                suchen.einstellungen);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(benutzername, passwort, sprache, datenname, suchwerte, einstellungen);
    }
}
```

```java
final String requestData = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(requestPojo);
```

`requestData` looks like this:

```xml
<Suchen>
  <benutzername>test</benutzername>
  <passwort>test</passwort>
  <sprache>De</sprache>
  <datenname>Arten</datenname>
  <suchwerte/>
  <einstellungen/>
</Suchen>
```

Which does not meet the requirements at all.

So how can I add those special namespaces  `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws1="http://ws1.myapi.ch/`?

What is the best way to add those element name prefixes like `<ws1:Suchen>`?

Comment: Please let us know if you figured out the way to achieve this?

Comment: @RajRaj ok I'm working it.

Comment: @RajRaj What type of project is it- Spring Boot or J2EE?

Comment: To add namespaces and prefixes to your XML request, you can use the Java API for XML Processing (JAXP) to generate the XML with the required namespaces and prefixes.

Answer (score -2):

In order to serialize your `Suchen` class with namespaces using `XmlMapper`, you need to use the `@XmlSchema`, `@XmlNs`, and `@XmlElement` annotations from the `javax.xml.bind.annotation` package to specify the namespace and prefix information.

Below is the step-by-step guide to achieve the desired XML output with namespaces:

#### 1. **Define the Namespace and Prefix**

Use the `@XmlSchema` and `@XmlNs` annotations on your package to define the namespace and prefix. Create a file named `package-info.java` in the same package as your `Suchen` class:

```java
@XmlSchema(
    xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(prefix = "ws1", namespaceURI = "http://ws1.myapi.ch/")
    },
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package your.package.name;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

2. **Annotate Your Class and Fields:**
   Annotate your `Suchen` class and its fields with the `@XmlElement` annotation, specifying the namespace and name.

```java
       @XmlRootElement(name = "Suchen", namespace = "http://ws1.myapi.ch/")
       public class Suchen {
           @XmlElement(name = "Benutzername", namespace = "http://ws1.myapi.ch/")
           protected String benutzername;
           // ... other fields with similar annotations
       }
```

3. **Serialize the Object:**
   Use XmlMapper to serialize the `Suchen` object, which should now include the namespace and prefix information.

   ```java
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
       String requestData = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new Suchen());
   ```

4. **Add Envelope and Body Manually**
   Since XmlMapper will only serialize the `Suchen` object, you may need to manually add the `soapenv:Envelope` and `soapenv:Body` elements to the XML string, or create corresponding classes for them and serialize the entire envelope object.

   **Full Example:**
   Here's a full example, assuming you have added the `package-info.java` as mentioned:

   ```java
     @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
       @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
           "benutzername",
           "passwort",
           "sprache",
           "datenname",
           "einstellungen"
       })
       @XmlRootElement(name = "Suchen", namespace = "http://ws1.myapi.ch/")
       public class Suchen {
           @XmlElement(name = "Benutzername", namespace = "http://ws1.myapi.ch/")
           protected String benutzername;
           // ... other fields and methods with similar annotations
       }
   ```

By following these steps, you should be able to generate the desired XML output with the correct namespace and prefix information.